# react-query callback function isn't receiving queryKey array as params

Tags: reactjs, react-query

```
const fetchData = async (key, compId, tmId) => {
    console.log('params: ', { key, compId, tmId });

    let url = `/this-path/comp/${compId}/tm/${tmId}`;
    const result = await axios.get(url);
    return result.data;
};

const fetchOutput = useQuery(['string-key', 231, 1053039], fetchData);
```

In the example above, we need the `fetchData()` parameter compId to equal `231`, and tmId to equal `1053039`. Based on my understanding of react-query, I thought that I would get this. However, instead we get this:

[image]

...where the queryKey array is accessable at key.queryKey, however the params `compId` and `tmId` are undefined, even though we're using useQuery() as such: `useQuery(['string-key', 231, 1053039], fetchData)`...

Is there something we're missing here? How can we get these values to serve as parameters for the callback `fetchData` function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

this, from the v3 migration guide, answers my question...